# How to Expose a DependencyProperty of a Control nested in a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, binding, nested, dependency-properties

I'm trying to bind an Image down from a Window into a UserControl 'Display' thats inside a UserControl 'DisplayHandler'. Display has a DependancyProperty 'DisplayImage'.
This is Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741178/wpf-nested-usercontrol-bindings), but their answers didn't help with my problem.

DisplayHandler also should have the Property 'DisplayImage' and pass down the Binding to Display. But Visual Studio doesn't allow me to register a DependancyProperty with the same name twice. So I tried to not register it twice but only to reuse it:

**window**

```
<my:DisplayHandler DisplayImage=
    "{Binding ElementName=ImageList, Path=SelectedItem.Image}" />
```

**DisplayHandler**

xaml

```
<my:Display x:Name="display1"/>
```

cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayImageProperty =
    myHWindowCtrl.DisplayImageProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DisplayHandler));

public HImage DisplayImage {
    get { return (HImage)GetValue(DisplayImageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayImageProperty, value); }
}
public HImage DisplayImage /*alternative*/ {
    get { return (HImage)display1.GetValue(Display.DisplayImageProperty); }
    set { display1.SetValue(Display.DisplayImageProperty, value); }
}
```

**neither of the 2 properties worked out.*

**Display**

```
public HImage DisplayImage {
    get { return (HImage)GetValue(DisplayImageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(DisplayImageProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayImage", typeof(HImage), typeof(Display));
```

---

I have been thinking a Control goes up the Tree and looks for its Property if its own Value is not defined. [->reference](http://www.wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html)

So it **should** work somehow...

I made some attempts with Templating and A ContentPresenter because that worked for the ImageList(ImageList also contains the Display), but I couldn't get it to bind the value like for an ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `AddOwner` solution should be working, but you have to add a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) that updates the embedded control.

```
public partial class DisplayHandler : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayImageProperty =
        Display.DisplayImageProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DisplayHandler),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DisplayImagePropertyChanged));

    public HImage DisplayImage
    {
        get { return (Image)GetValue(DisplayImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayImageProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void DisplayImagePropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dh = obj as DisplayHandler;
        dh.display1.DisplayImage = e.NewValue as HImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works fine. But I just found out, adding
`DisplayImage="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=hview:DisplayHandler}, Path=DisplayImage}"/>` additionally supports me with twoway Binding.

Comment: I just hoped it was the _same_ DP and so the ChangeNotification would work. This way it seems, it again stores the value twice. Am I wrong?

Comment: It is actually the same DP, but it stores the value twice. First  it stores the value on the DisplayHandler, and then (in the PropertyCangedCallback) on the embedded Display instance. But what's the problem? It's just storing an object reference. Or is HImage a large struct?

Comment: Nono its perfectly fine. Of course theres no problem in a double reference... silly me -.-