# How to Expose multiple DependencyProperties (with same Name) of nested Controls in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, nested, dependency-properties

I tried to solve almost same problem: "[How to Expose a DependencyProperty of a Control nested in a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14279236/how-to-expose-a-dependencyproperty-of-a-control-nested-in-a-usercontrol/14279745#comment32629609_14279745)"

The difference is that I have different (2 or more) nested `Controls` with of the same `type`. My goal is to make the nested `DependencyProperties` bindable. The main Problem I am facing is that `Binding` don't uses the the `Getter` and `Setter` of the `CLR-Property` but the `String` of the registererd `DependencyProperty`. With 2 (or more) nested `Controls` I am facing a naming conflict.

To illustrate my Problem here the Code of the outer `UserControl`:

```
public partial class OuterControl : UserControl
{
    public OuterControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Visibility PropOfInnerControl
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(PropOfInnerControlProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PropOfInnerControlProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for UserControl2Visibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropOfInnerControlProperty =
        InnerControl.PropOfInnerControlProperty.AddOwner(typeof(OuterControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(MyVisibilityPropertyChanged));            

    private static void MyVisibilityPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var OuterControl = obj as OuterControl;
        OuterControl.InnerControl1.PropOfInnerControl = (Visibility)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

If it's not clear: In my example the `DependencyProperty` of the `InnerControl1` is called `PropOfInnerControlProperty` and is registerd under the `String "PropOfInnerControl"`.

In my example Binding with the `InnerControl1` works fine. But I don't know how to resolve the same Problem with the `InnerControl2`.